# Uncollapsing margins between in-flow siblings

Tags: css, margin

This is what makes me cry at night. One would wish that CSS had a directive `margin-collapse:none;`, but alas, that is from my imagination.

How do you get two in-flow siblings not to collapse?

I have tried `overflow:hidden`, `clear:both`, `border:1px solid white` both on the element and generating an element before, nothing works.

Here's [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/dkYPA/). H2's are removed from the flow to look pretty on the side, not collapsing, while H3 sits there collapsing with its predecessor no matter what. Now margin collapsing makes the vertical alignment of H2 and H3 in a coherent fashion, independent of the preceding element, impossible.

The constraint: HTML markup cannot be added, as the content is generated via Markdown.

Is this solvable?

**Edit**: In fact, the goal here was to make the `h2`  and their first `h3` to come up at the same height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### One Solution

In your particular case, it appears that you would not necessarily need to take `h2` out of flow, and rather set it to `position: relative`, because [it should achieve the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/dkYPA/4/) you want.

However, that does not really solve your question of margin collapse.

### Another Solution

If you set the `h3` that follows an `h2` to `display: inline-block`, using...

```
h2+h3 {display: inline-block;}
```

...then [**it resolves your collapsing issue**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkYPA/5/), assuming you do not have `inline` [elements immediately following](http://jsfiddle.net/dkYPA/7/) the `h3` tag. It appears that you plan on having any following text in a block level `p` tag, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: In fact it has to be removed from the flow to be at the same height with the `h3`. As for the inline block, it seems to do the trick. We could even add a generated block element after for the following inline elements not to come up. It's an ugly hack, but it does work.

Comment: Taking the `h2` back into flow was what I did in the end. I ended up putting a `margin-bottom:-1.33em` (beats me why the 1/3 increment, exactly) and `margin:0` on all following elements (`h2+*`).

I'll award the answer here because it is the most simple, and that taking `h2` back into flow was suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fix I came up with:

```
.ncFix {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*ensures width isn't cropped. 
  acts as width: auto - like a
  regular block-level element*/
.ncFix:before {
  content:". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

That pseudo element makes the element's `width: auto` act as if the `width: auto` of an element with `display: block`. It's a long string on the content 'property' but it's pretty much the only way I can think of to make it work.

Take a look at the demo -> http://tinkerbin.com/H3G7HjWg

Comment: It works. The shortcoming is the dot string. That is one ugly hack. The thing is, if we downsize the font, we need more dots. I wonder if there's something else besides `inline-block`...

Comment: Ya, it is one ugly hack. I'm still thinking about this problem though.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to avoid the two margins collapsing together? Could you add a 1px white border to the h3 tag (and adjust it's margin by 1px to compensate)? I think this should keep the margins from collapsing.

Comment: I forgot to say I tried that as well. As [we can see](http://jsfiddle.net/dkYPA/2/), it still collapses.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote your css - it looked a bit off key to me

```
*{
 border: 1px solid red;   
}
html {}
body{ border:0 solid gray; border-top:none; border-bottom:none;
   width:8.5in; margin:auto;
   font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:1em; padding-left:3.5in; }

h1{ font-size:36pt;}
h2, h3{
 display: block;   
}
h2{margin-left: -200px; display: block; float: left}
h3{margin-top: 40px;}
```

Also in the HTML one of your UL tags wasn't closed properly (it was closed with ul instead of /ul. Which caused an issue.

I'd also recommend using pixels instead of inches in your sizes - inches and centimeters can sometimes produce unreliable results in terms of layout.

Comment: Besides typos and inches, what did you fix and how?